# bulk insert returning error, "the file could not be opened"

Tags: sql-server

I am running the following query in SQL Server 11.0.

```
BULK INSERT [dbo].[Andy] FROM "Y:\users\joe\APP data main file.csv"
              WITH (FIRSTROW = 2, FIELDTERMINATOR = ',' ,
              ROWTERMINATOR = '\n', TABLOCK)
```

The command is returning the error,

> Cannot bulk load because the file "Y:\users\joe\APP data main
>   file.csv" could not be opened. Operating system error code 3(The
>   system cannot find the path specified.).

The cause of this error, from researching it online, is that the Bulk Insert task runs by executing the Bulk Insert command from the target SQL server to load the file. This means that the SQL Server Agent of the target SQL server should have permissions on the file I am trying to load. **How can I find out whether it does or not?**

Secondly, according to Microsoft’s website, “…if a SQL Server user logs on by using Windows Authentication, the user can read only those files that can be accessed by the user account, regardless of the security profile of the SQL Server process.”

I log onto SQL Server using Windows Authentication. By the definition on the MS website, I have access to the file I am trying to insert from. I created it, and I can open it. More specifically, the Windows account I’ve logged onto (my own) is the account that created the csv file, and is the account through which I open SQL Server. Yet the error is there. There is something I am missing, but I have no idea what it is.

Finally, it doesn’t matter whether or not I use the UNC path to access the file, or the drive mapping.

Comment: Please emit spaces from filename and try

Comment: This makes no difference, the same error is returned.

Comment: Go to file explorer>Navigate to file> Right click on file> Properties>Security tab>Check permissions for users.

Comment: Could you update your error after using UNC and omitting spaces.

Comment: After using ANC and omitting spaces, the error changes to "Operating system error code 53(The network path was not found.)"

Comment: I checked permissions for users. There are 4 sets of names under "group or user names". All 4 have a minimum of read acess. I was able to change all 4 groups to have full control and modify access (although all they need is read access on that file anyway). This didn't make any difference to the bulk insert command either though.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the file is located on network server, you are referencing mapped drive name, try use UNC network path instead.

Comment: As i stated at the end of the original description, it makes no difference whether I use the UNC mapping or not.

Answer (score -1):

I had an email back from my IT department on this question:

> The problem I think is that you’re assigned to a server role based on
>   the user policy group that you’ve been assigned to - which would
>   correspond with a particular server role - by the network
>   administrators and this server role doesn’t have access to the file
>   path for whatever reason. You may have access to the server path
>   yourself because of another group to which you currently are assigned
>   but if that group doesn’t correspond with the server role, the server
>   role won’t have access.

So there we have it. It has since transpired that I can't bulk upload anyway for operational reasons, so I won't be pursuing this any further.

Thanks all for your help.